# When to use "vary depend on" and "vary depending on"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, phrase-usage, phrase-choice, sentence-choice

I found these examples:

Source: https://uk.practicallaw.thomsonreuters.com/7-508-0012?transitionType=Default&contextData=(sc.Default)

> The purchase of real estate is subject to transfer tax (ITBI). The
> taxpayer and the rates **vary depend on** the municipality where the
> property is located. The rates typically range between 2 and 4 per
> cent of the purchase price of the property.
>
> Typically, the buyer pays the Notary Public and the Real Estate
> Registry Office fees, except if otherwise agreed by the parties.
> Public Notary and Registration fees **vary depending on** the State where
> the property is located.

and

Source: https://www.bradfordjacobs.com/countries/greece-employee-benefits/

> In Greece, compensation laws **vary depend on** the employee
> classification and the sector they are working in. Employers must also
> keep in mind that benefits also **vary depending on** the applicable
> collective labor agreements or internal work regulations of the
> company.

Comment: The ones without the -ing suffix appear to be typos.  Those sentences are improved by using the -ing version.

Comment: "Typo" is slang for a mistake in typed or written text.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about a couple of relatively uncommon typesetting errors

Answer (score 2):

The ones without the -ing suffix appear to be typos. That is, mistakes.

They ought to include -ing.

Is "vary depend on" ever correct?  Well, sometimes "vary, depend on" (with a comma) might be. We could imagine such text:

"In Greece, compensation laws *vary, depend on* the employee classification, and are generally seen as fair to workers."

Comment: For native speakers, your "contrived" version might be seen as "interesting". But for *learners*, I think it's just pointlessly confusing (I doubt any native speaker would *actually* produce such an utterance "for real").